# how to connect html button to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, web

i recently started to do web programming.
i got a task that using javascript.

what i'm trying to do is that i type some text in texture and if i press a button, it makes text size changed 
so

1) type text in textarea

2) press a button

3) a button calls javascript function from javascript file

4) function changes text size and returns it to somewhere(?)

5) size-changed text is displayed in texture

i think i did 1~3 but not 100% sure

this is my code :

```js
function doFunction() {
     var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
     var result = txt.fontsize(24); 
    }
```

```html
<h1>Pimp My Text</h1>
        <div>
            <img  src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/190m/09sp/labs/5-pimpify/pimpin.jpg" alt="Marty Stepp, pimpin' it!" />
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Text</legend>
            <textarea rows ="3" cols= "30" id="txt">
            </textarea>
            
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Pimpification</legend>
            <input type="button" value="Bigger pimpin!"  onclick="doFunction();"/
    </br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Bling" />Bling
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: What do you intend to return changing font size?

Comment: just like pressing button changes text size.

Comment: So it doesn't return anything? Returning something means you put some new data in a variable's value.

Comment: i just thought maybe i could use return to change font size. this is not necessary to use :d

Comment: I think I've found you what you want to do. Unfortunately, this approach is obsolete and nobody should learn anymore. The better approach is to use CSS for the fontsize.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "texture"? Bold or italic? Font change? Size change?

Comment: Also, you should learn **event listener** and stay away from `onclick`s if you are doing a bigger page.

Comment: sorry mistyped texture -> text. i'm trying to figure out class and event things :)......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `javascript` for this to increase the font size. You can change the font size value to you preferred value.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Pimp My Text</h1>
    <div>
        <img  src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/190m/09sp/labs/5-pimpify/pimpin.jpg" alt="Marty Stepp, pimpin' it!" />
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Text</legend>
        <textarea rows ="3" cols= "30" id="txt">
        </textarea>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pimpification</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Bigger pimpin!"  onclick="doFunction();"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Bling" />Bling
    </fieldset>
    
    <script>
      function doFunction() {
      document.getElementById("txt").style.fontSize = "30px";
      }
    </script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: As you can see from the snippet, it works. Hmm have you tried to copy everything from `<body>` to `</body>` ?

Comment: i did copy and it works now :o............................ i thought i typed just exactly same thing but guess it wasn't same............... (lol i can't believe myself now haha)  thx for help!!

Comment: ah no.. i typed same thing. i compared every characters... i don't get this.

Comment: Glad it works :) Well, I forgot to mention this but in your code, there was a syntax error which I already fixed. `<input type="button" value="Bigger pimpin!"  onclick="doFunction();"/` , you forgot to close it with the `>` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

First give your text are some default font-size with CSS:

```
#txt {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Then call this function each time your button is clicked.

Javascript **without** JQuery:

```
function increaseTextSize() {
    document.getElementById("#txt").style.fontSize = "30px";
}
```

Javascript using JQuery:

```
function increaseTextSize() {
    $("#txt").css("font-size", "30px");
}
```

HTML changes required

Change

```
onclick="doFunction();"
```

to

```
onclick="increaseTextSize();"
```

Code Snippet -

```js
function increaseTextSize() {
        document.getElementById("txt").style.fontSize = "30px";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Pimp My Text</h1>
    <div>
        <img  src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/190m/09sp/labs/5-pimpify/pimpin.jpg" alt="Marty Stepp, pimpin' it!" />
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Text</legend>
        <textarea rows ="3" cols= "30" id="txt">
        </textarea>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pimpification</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Bigger pimpin!"  onclick="increaseTextSize();"/
</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Bling" />Bling
    </fieldset>

    </body>
```

Comment: Why everyone comment with JQuery ... install a lib just for changing a css ONE time is weird ...

Comment: If jQuery is not mentioned in the question, OP is likely not looking for a JQuery-based solution. Therefore you should put a disclaimer that your answer requires additional JS libraries.

Comment: jQuery didn't mentioned in the chapter that i'm learning now :o.... btw thanks for comment :D

Comment: @Terry I have put a disclaimer now.

Comment: @YuminHwang I have updated the answer you can do this **without** JQuery too.

Comment: @YasserHussain how to connect above function to button and textarea??

Comment: @YuminHwang Did you get a chance to try my answer??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update TextArea text size from it number input you can update your JS function to:

```
function doFunction() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    document.getElementById("txt").style.fontSize = txt.trim() + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2D scaling transformation enables you to resize an element. To perform a 2D scaling transformation.

The following CSS rule scales a `<div>` element with the class scale1. The element is 30 percent larger in all dimensions:

div.scale1 {   transform: scale(1.3); }

Then use JavaScript to add the class attribute 'scale1' to the element

elementName.classList.add("scale1");

Comment: i nvr learned this 2d scaling. my task requires to use java script function some library things :c .....